# Как собрать elf и запустить пример из репозитория?

Tags: linux, c, elf

Я нашёл в [репозитории гитхаба](https://github.com/niicoooo/esp32-elfloader) пример elf-loader'а, который я хочу запустить,чтобы создать blob.

Но я не могу понять, как собрать пример. В ELF creation, где указаны папки   `moduleexample and payloadexamples` этих папок попросту нет. Там есть файлы с расширениями .ld, но я не пойму, как такие собирать или линковать.Makefile'ы не рабочие оказались(или мне кажется?). Почему не используется -fPIC при линковке для получения elf-файла? В общем, можете пожалуйста, помочь собрать пример с созданием elf'a и использования elf-loader'a?

Comment: вам явно сюда: https://github.com/niicoooo/esp32-elfloader/issues

Comment: Ну _*.ld_ файлы -- это скрипты линковщика.

Comment: _-fPIC_ -- опционален вообще-то говоря к базовому формату.

Comment: И наконец, вы ESP-IDF поставили?